# Unable to receive String Data from Python Socket to Java Socket

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am having trouble with using sockets

As you can see the codes worked when I tried to send string from JAVA to PYTHON.

**But however I am having trouble when I tried to send string from PYTHON to JAVA ,which is the opposite way. And I need it to convert into bytes and decode it since I encoded the string before I send it over.**

Thus the problem now is how or is there anything wrong in my codes when I send a string from Python socket and receiving the string by Java Socket?

I really need help, thank you!

Python (SERVER) Codes:

```
import socket
import ssl
import hashlib
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random 

sHost = ''
sPort = 1234


def bindSocket():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #IPv4 and TCP
    try:
        s.bind((sHost,sPort))
        print("Socket created and binded")
    except socket.error as msgError:
        print(msgError)
        print("Error in Binding Socket")
    return s #so that we can use it


def socketConnect():
    s.listen(1) #listen to 1 connection at a time


    while True:
        try:
            conn, address = s.accept() #Accept connection from client
            print ("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" +str(address[1]))
        except socket.error as error:
            print ("Error: {0}" .format(e))
            print ("Unable to start socket")
        return conn






def loopCommand(conn):
    while True:
        passphrase = "Hello Java Client "
        data = conn.recv(1024)#receive the message sent by client

        print(data)

        conn.send(passphrase.encode('utf-8'))

        print("Another String is sent to Java")

s = bindSocket()

while True:
    try:
        conn = socketConnect()
        loopCommand(conn)
    except:
        pass
```

Java (Client) Codes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SocketSTesting {

    public Socket socketStartConnect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        String ip = "192.168.1.16";
        int port = 1234;
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("It is connected to the server which is " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());

        } else if (clientSocket.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed");
        }
        return clientSocket;
    }

    public void sendString(String str) throws Exception {

        // Get the socket's output stream
        Socket socket = socketStartConnect();
        OutputStream socketOutput = socket.getOutputStream();

        byte[] strBytes = str.getBytes();



        // total byte
        byte[] totalByteCombine = new byte[strBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(strBytes, 0, totalByteCombine, 0, strBytes.length);

        //Send to Python Server
        socketOutput.write(totalByteCombine, 0, totalByteCombine.length);
        System.out.println("Content sent successfully");


        //Receieve Python string
        InputStream socketInput = socket.getInputStream();
        String messagetype = socketOutput.toString();
        System.out.println(messagetype);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SocketSTesting client = new SocketSTesting();

        String str = "Hello Python Server!";
        client.sendString(str);


    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but it's certainly _a_ problem. [TCP is not a stream of messages, it's just a stream of bytes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). So how is Java supposed to know when you've sent your whole string? It's like expecting Java to knowwhereawordendswhenyoudon'tputanyspaces. You need some kind of framing, like maybe a newline at the end of the string, so it knows to read until a newline.

Comment: But meanwhile, you don't seem to be even trying to read anything from the inputstream. Instead, you're just converting the output stream to a string and printing that. That's why you're not seeing any data from Python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to think that `String messagetype = socketOutput.toString();` performs I/O. It doesn't, so printing it or even calling it does nothing and proves nothing. You need to *read* from the socket *input* stream.

BTW `clientSocket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. If the connect had failed, an exception would have been thrown. Similarly, `clientSocket.isClosed()` cannot possibly be true at the point you are testing it, because you haven't closed the socket you just created. Further, if `isClosed()` was true it would not mean 'connection failed', and `isConnected()` being false does not entail `isClosed()` being true. Remove all this.